# bcp Issue with Query SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I have been experimenting with `bcp` because its a very elegant way to create text files. However, for some reason my query isn't working. I am sure it's something terribly simple but I would appreciate if someone could point out where I am dumb.

As I am not terribly familiar with `bcp`, is it due to maybe the (, [, ] characters? Do I need to escape these characters with "?

```
declare @Result int

exec @Result = master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 
                     'bcp "SELECT ''H'', 1227, 1227, 1227, 1227, 
                                  [Check Num], GETDATE(), [Control Num], 
                                  [Clm Spec 1], [Clm Date], [Dlr Num], 
                                  UPPER([Dlr Name]), [Amt Claimed], 
                                  [Amt Appr], [Amt Paid], 
                                  Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip + ''|''     
                           FROM DBNAME.dbo.tblName" queryout "C:\MyTable.txt" -c -t"|" -S SERVERNAME -T'
```

Comment: Running that command from a cmd command line  instead of from within SQL would be a lot easier to debug : you'd be able to read the error message for a start?

Comment: Well that would just be smart of me lol

Comment: I suspect the problem is because, unlike SQL, the cmdshell doesn't cope with a command split over several lines. If you must work from with SQL, try writing that whole command on one long line and see if you get a result?

Comment: While i was waiting for response I ended up going bcp escape characters - found the multiple line escape charactar. Trying that now. If that doesnt work ill try the 1 line thing.  Thank you

Comment: Turns out the real issue was that you must have everything in one line for the command prompt. I rewrote the sql appropriately

Comment: it will be much easier to handle if can create a stored procedure and then call it from `BCP queryout`

Comment: Have you tried running the select query separate first? If so, did you receive an error and what was the error?

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll if you want to post that as an answer you will get the deserved points/creds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike SQL, `cmd.exe` doesn't cope with a command split over several lines. If you rewrite the command all on one line, you'll get a result.

(cmd.exe does allow `^` as a line-continuation marker, but quotation marks break it)

But if you have access to the server, basic bcp operations are probably easier to do straight from a command line. And PowerShell happily lets you write and edit multi-line quoted strings.